# How to update the value inside object in React native and Asyncstorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object, asyncstorage

I am new to react native. I have used Asyncstorage to store the data in key = 'name' and want to use this value inside meta data object to send with cart. i am not able to update the value inside the object.

I want to add the textinput value from my Customtext component to the "value" : in

**FYI the function is in the common folder and CustomText is in the Components folder.**

```
item.meta_data= [{
 "key" : "custom_text", 
 "value" : 
}]
```

Here is the component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import Tools from '../../common/Tools';


class CustomText extends Component {

   constructor(){
   super()
      this.state = {
      'name': ''
   }
}



   componentDidMount = () => AsyncStorage.getItem('name').then((value) => this.setState({ 'name': value }))
   

   setName = (value) => {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('name', value);
      this.setState({ 'name': value });
      // console.log(value);
      // DefaultPreference.set('name', value).then(function() {alert('done')});
   }
   

   render() {


      return (
         <View style = {styles.container}>
           
           <Text style={{
              top:-250,
              left: 8,
              fontWeight:'bold' }}>
               {this.state.name}
            </Text>
           
            <TextInput 
            style={styles.nameInput} 
            autoCapitalize = 'none'
            onChangeText = {this.setName}  
            />
           

          

         </View>
      )
   }
}
export default CustomText



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 8,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 6,
    color: 'white'
  },
  nameInput: {
    fontSize: 14,
    marginBottom: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 12,
    width: '80%',
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  image: {
    width: 10,
    height: 20,
    borderColor: 'orange',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 100,
  }


});
```

and this is the function in which i want to update the value

```
static getItemsToCheckout = (cartItems) => {
    const items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
      const cartItem = cartItems[i];

      const item = {
        product_id: cartItem.product.id,
        quantity: cartItem.quantity,
        
      };

      if (cartItem.variation !== null) {
        item.variation_id = cartItem.variation.id;   
      }
      
      item.meta_data=[
        { 
        "key" : "custom_text",
        "value" : **WANT TO UPDATE HERE**
      }
      ]    
      items.push(item);

    }
    return items;
  };
}
```

Comment: Please don't write anything in ALL CAPS.

Comment: Thanks James Z...will keep this in mind

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
setName = (value) => {
      let newValue = this.state.name;
      newValue.custom_text = value;          

      AsyncStorage.setItem('name', newValue);
      this.setState({ 'name': newValue });
}
```

Comment: But how will i update the value in the item.meta_data object??
It is still not getting updated..

Comment: where are you calling that function? have you try to load it from AsyncStorage?

Comment: I CALL THAT FUNCTION DURING THE CHECKOUT
if (Config.EnableOnePageCheckout) {
            const order = {
              line_items: Tools.getItemsToCheckout(this.props.cartItems),
              token:
                this.props.user && this.props.user.token
                  ? this.props.user.token
                  : null,
            };

Comment: Václav Ryska Yes i tried to load it from asyncstorage